# mysql data type for time

Tags: mysql, time

When we create a table in mySQL (via phpMyAdmin), what 'type' and 'default' should be selected to set time?

My project is "IOT based collage bell management System in PHP and MySql"

mysql data:

```
-------------------------------------------
bell no.       on time           off time
--------       --------          ---------
bell1          09:00:00          09:00:09
bell2          10:00:00          10:00:09
bell3          11:00:00          11:00:09
```

- When we set `bell1` on time at `9:00:00` then this time is saved in the server and at that time the buzzer is on.
- When we set `bell1` off time at `9:00:09` then after 9 seconds the buzzer is turned off.

Buzzer on and off time is saved in the server.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f8720ce95f35e4ba6d7d649fb757ee7 .

Comment: Data logic does not provide definite DEFAULT value - do not specify it, let's it to be NULL. But do not forget to add CHECK constraint which checks that off time is greater than on time. PS. If the difference between on and off times is always 9 second then off time column is obviously excess.